# How to swap the keys Alt with AltGr?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I would like to use the key <kbd>AltGr</kbd> as my main <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. Unfortunately, the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> doesn't behave like the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key with the software I use, e.g. `urxvt`.

With the command `xev` the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key has the **keycode 64**, and the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> has the **keycode 108**.

`$ xmodmap -pke` gives me the following result for the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and the right <kbd>AltGr</kbd> keys:

```
keycode  64 = Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L
keycode 108 = ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift
```

To be brief, I would like to swap the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, with the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key.

I'm using 14.04 server.

Answer (score 7):

Found the solution by myself :-)

```
$ xmodmap .Xmodmap
```

The `.Xmodmap` file should contain the following:

```
! Swap Mod1 and Mod5
!
remove Mod1 = Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L
remove Mod5 = ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift
keysym Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L = ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift
keysym ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift = Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L
add Mod1 = Alt_L Meta_L
add Mod5 = ISO_Level3_Shif
```